# MongoDB: how to return distinct data with filtering

Tags: mongodb, symfony, dictionary, reduce

I have a "Post" collection with a lot of posts and I want to retrieve distinct `YearMonth` value from `post.published_date`

Return Example:

```
['201303', '201301', '201212' ... ... ]
```

I'm using Symfony2 + DoctrineMongoDB.
I think I've to use the QueryBuilder with map and reduce functions, but I'm not able to use them!

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please could you post and example of your document structure?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to filter the dates on the client side, but if you really need to filter on the server you can you the aggregation frameworks $unwind/$addToSet trick. Something like this:

```
db.post.aggregate([
        {$match: ...}, // your match here
        {$project: {
               published_date: 1
        }},
        {$unwind: "$published_date"},
        {$group: {
             _id: "$_id",
             unique_published_date: {$addToSet: "$published_date"}
        }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using symfony2 and mongo db you can create a repository for the collection as below and call the repository function `findDistinctYearMonth`

```
class PostRepository extends DocumentRepository {    
    public function findDistinctYearMonth()
            {
                $yearMonths = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->map('function() {
                    var yearMonth =
                    emit("" + this.published_date.getFullYear()+("0"+(this.published_date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),1);
                    }')
                    ->reduce('function(k,v) {
                       return 1;
                    }')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();

    $arr = array();
    foreach($yearMonths as $yearMonth) {
        $arr[] = $yearMonth["_id"];
    }
    return $arr;
}
}
```